# How To fetch values from Hazelcast IMap using predicate?

Tags: hazelcast

My Imap is of below type

IMap(String,List(USER)) hazelcasttestMap =hazelcastInstance.getMap("UserMap");

```
List<USER> userList= hazelcasttestMap .get(id);
    Predicate criteriaQuery = Predicates.equal("userList[any].userId", "12345");
  hazelcasttestMap .values(criteriaQuery).iterator().next();
```

I want List which should have userId as 12345.

Comment: Can someone answer on above query